# Typing Custom Renderers [ Gatsby & Contenful Richtext ]

Tags: javascript, typescript, gatsby, contentful

I've been messing around with trying to type my gatsby contentful richtext custom renderers for quite some time now, but unfortunately without much success.

Can someone lead me on the right track how to type {children} in my const Bold & const Text without this shady "any" hack?

```
const Bold = ({ children }: any) => <p className="bold">{children}</p>
const Text = ({ children }: any) => <p className="paragraph">{children}</p>

const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: (text: ReactNode) => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node: ReactNode, children: ReactNode) => (
      <Text>{children}</Text>
    ),
  },
}
```

THX in advance and best regards from Vienna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper footprint would be `({ children }: { children: React.ReactChildren }) =>...` as the children ARE React Children and it expects no other React provided properties. If you need other React properties and custom properties from the Props object instead you'd type it with `React.propsWithChildren<T>` the type.

```js
const Bold = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactChildren }) => <p className="bold">{children}</p>
const Text = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactChildren }) => <p className="paragraph">{children}</p>
```

Comment: THX Robert for your answer, you've guided me to the final solution. I've edited your answer with the code which actually got things working.

Comment: If my answer was then right one then be sure to accept it as the right answer so people know